# Undefined 'model' property of Keystonejs List object

Tags: keystonejs

I created an example with a very simple list (of countries) and created api routes based on the instructions found here: https://gist.github.com/JedWatson/9741171

server.js:

`app.get('/api/countries', keystone.middleware.api, routes.api.countries.list);`

routes/api/countries.js:

```
import keystone from 'keystone';

export function list(req, res) {
  keystone.List('Country').model.find((err, items) => {
    if (err) return res.apiError('database error', err);

    res.apiResponse({
      countries: items
    });
  });
}
```

I get the error `Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`, the List object exists but it doesn't have a `model` property. Does anyone know why this is? The keystone admin UI works as expected and there are several objects in the database.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was that I used `keystone.List` (capitalized) instead of `keystone.list`. Hopefully someone else will be helped by this answer.